# Magento Availability error on configurable product importing stock csv

Tags: magento, csv

I have a small script which imports my seller stock availability on my Magento store.

It work perfectly with simple product and child product but have some strange problem with configurable products.
When the script run it put random product which are configurable as "not available".

I had to go to admin, select all product which are configurable with view "catalog/search" (for be sure to select only parent configurable products) and change all their attributes on inventory as "available".

There's any way to not have stock check working only on configurable products?
This is my script, anyone see something wrong or can help me on how to put at the and another recursive check for put all the configurable products as available?

```
<?php
define('MAGE_BASE_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(MAGE_BASE_DIR.'/app/Mage.php');

$file = MAGE_BASE_DIR."/var/import/stock.csv";


$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle) {
require_once(MAGE_BASE_DIR.'/app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

while (!feof($handle)) {
   $linea = fgets($handle);
   $linea2 = str_replace('"', '', $linea);
    $dati = explode(";", $linea2);



$ref = trim($dati[0]);
    $sku = trim($dati[1]);
    $titolo = trim ($dati[2]);
    $qta = trim($dati[3]);
    $disponibile = trim($dati[4]);

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');

    $productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);
    if ($productId !== false) {
        $product->load($productId);

        $stockItem->loadByProduct($productId);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $qta);
        $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', ($qta > 0) ? 1 : 0);

        try {
            $stockItem->save();
            echo "<span style='color:#ff0000; weight:bold;'>{$sku} elaborato     correttamente.</span> ";
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $countException++;
            echo "{$sku} errore ({$e->getMessage()}). ";
        }
    } else {
        echo "{$sku} non trovato.";
    }

    unset($product);
    unset($stockItem);
}
fclose($handle);    
} else {
echo "Errore apertura file. ({$file})";
exit();}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are wrong input data. Magento do not save qty for configurable products. I think that you should not update the stock item for configurable products.

Moreover you are loading the product model, but you are not using it. Try to comment this line

```
$product->load($productId);
```

your script should be much faster.